# How to set path for C++ program?

Tags: c++

I set the path for c++ and I can compile it, but when I run it, the console shows that

> ./CheckBML
>   '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I think it is because the program cannot find my file.

Do you guys know how to get rid of ".\"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking? Are you using Linux?

Comment: `./CheckBML`  is it a service ?

Comment: Are you trying to set the working directory? How are you running the program? How are you trying to run the command that's failing?

Comment: please share your code snippet.

Comment: I am using c++. I can run my program by typing >CheckBML in my console, but when I click "run", it appears the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

You are typing a *nix command and getting a Windows error. The command shells work differently on *nix and Windows.

Windows cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Ahaman\prog\BML> CheckBML
```

Linux/Unix/etc /usr/bin/bash (or whatever)

```
~/prog/BML% ./CheckBML
```